# Check if something is between two values?

Tags: php, date, if-statement, compare, between

How do I go about checking to see if the current date is between two other dates?

I've been trying different operators, but haven't been able to figure this out.

So, if I have a `from` date of `2/2/2010` and a `to` date of `2/10/2010`, how can I return `TRUE` if the current date (`2/4/2010`) falls between those two dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a comparison like this you need to do separate comparisons.  If $d is the date you want to compare, $d1 is the earlier date, and $d2 is the later date, it would be something like:

```
if ((strtotime($d) > strtotime($d1)) and (strtotime($d) < strtotime($d2))) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head, I don't know of a date comparison operator in PHP, but I would use `strtotime()` on all three dates, then do simple mathematical comparisons.

```
<?php

$early_date = strtotime("02/02/2010");
$date = strtotime("02/04/2010");
$late_date = strtotime("02/10/2010");

if (($early_date < $date) && ($date < $late_date)) {
  echo "true";
}
```

returns true.

Answer (score 1):

If past date one *and* before date two, *then* it's between them.

Answer (score 1):

wouldn't this work ?

```
 ( ($lowerlimitdate <= $checkingdate) && ($checkingdate <= $upperlimitdate))
```

Answer (score 0):

the googles told me

```
if ( strtotime($date) > strtotime('22/09/2008') && strtotime($date) < strtotime('28/09/2008'))
```

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081003113922AAHnQsp