# Warning range() : The supplied range exceeds the maximum array size: start=0 end=1508715000

Tags: php, arrays, xampp

I'm getting this kind of error I can't find the same question is this new. I'm using PHP7 I doubt that is on memory_limit but my I already changed it to 1024M. I'm trying to determine whether is date is in between of two dates. Is there any way or how can I resolve this issue.

```
function isBetween ($from, $to, $input){
    $input = (is_int($input) ? $input : strtotime($input));
    $from = (is_int($from) ? $from : strtotime($from));
    $to = (is_int($to) ? $to : strtotime($to));

    if(in_array($input, range($from,$to)) ){
        return 1;        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `$input >= $from && $input <= $to`?

Comment: That one is good thanks but hope that to know what does error mean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php question... how to check if something is between two values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204725/php-question-how-to-check-if-something-is-between-two-values) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999831/check-if-todays-date-is-between-two-other-dates and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070116/php-check-if-date-between-two-dates

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to create such a huge array, just to check if a date is between two others. All you have to do (if you dont have your date already in unit timestamp format), is convert all dates to unix timestamps and do a simple if:

```
if ($startTimestamp < $input && $input < $to) {
    print 'Yay!';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do as tkausl says:

```
function isBetween ($from, $to, $input){
    $input = (is_int($input) ? $input : strtotime($input));
    $from = (is_int($from) ? $from : strtotime($from));
    $to = (is_int($to) ? $to : strtotime($to));
    return ($input>=$from && $input<=$to)?1:0;  // this is "inclusive" of the start and end
}
```

For information about array limitations, you can start your research journey here:

- [What is the maximum size of an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856506/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-array-in-php)
- [PHP: do arrays have a maximum size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036957/php-do-arrays-have-a-maximum-size)